# How can I get latest .vcf files with annotation data?

Tags: vcf, sequence-annotation, ngs

I'd like to perform the annotation (1000genomes, COSMIC etc.) of my variants using SnpSift and SnpEff, however so far all I get are vcf files for separate chromosomes:
http://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/

I'd like to annotate my variants and then filter out common SNP's. What in your opinion is best annotation source and where can I get the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `Somatic Sequence Variants`?,

if so, Table 1 inside the following full-text link:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5707196/

And additional information from my search-->
Here's
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hVtgMYAtvDoUcigKx8OLDmongDRzDQAd/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102408774767674945852&rtpof=true&sd=true

[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18JPIjuPZPM2hnj5O18T4HeQnNil3fU9u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RfIn2pIyr_zCyK18rQCX_J1Vr0OQ9Q4W/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l6M5xlKulDGQ2aFLz21TuNYY9s2LpFAd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s86a0gtDE-15h0r3UORfMux3pT8Ns1ls/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

According to your answer I tried to get the files which might be useful regarding annotation:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot,  how can you do all of that within 24 hrs?  Congratulations!